# Mac Bootable CD not loading

Tags: installation, mac, cd

I''m trying to install (dualboot) Ubuntu on my Macbook with installed Mac OS X Mountain Lion with Intel processors, and am running into some issues. I can burn the disk `.iso` fine, but when the problem starts when I reboot (I'm using the rEFIT boot loader). Here's what happens:

1. I turn on and the boot loader shows up. The Linux CD is not shown.
2. I reboot from rEFIT, which fixes the problem (by which I mean "Boot Linux CD" shows up.
3. I choose Linux CD, and it brings me to a black screen with a spacebar blinking.

That's it. No messages. No errors. Nothing. I'd say the mac froze, but the `_` cursor was constantly blinking. Any help?

Also, when this happens I can't shut the macbook down. The cursor just blinks. Eventually I'll be able to shut down by pressing the power button, but for a good half-hour at least the computer is completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

[`https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Harsha